# Facing an issue regarding compiling my project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone help me regarding the below issue I'm facing in the attached image. I'm trying to go to this url: http://localhost:49849/Customers but I couldn't. Thanks in advance... Just to let you know I;m following Mosh's Cource.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEuyz.jpg)

Here is the Model code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;   //this is a namespace

namespace Vidly2.Models
{
    public class Customers
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required] // we cal changing the conventions dataannotations
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
        public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; } // we call it navigation property because it allows us to navigate to another type
        public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; } //Fk
    }
}
```

here is the Controller code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly2.Models;


namespace Vidly2.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var customers = GetCustomers();

            return View(customers);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);

            if (customer == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

            return View(customer);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Customers> GetCustomers()
        {
            return new List<Customers>
            {
                new Customers { id =1, name = "John Smith" },
                new Customers { id =2, name = "Mary Williams" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the view code which has the mentioned error regarding compiling the project:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;


@model IEnumerable<Vidly2.Models.Customers>
@*
    Note: I've set the model for this view to IEnumerable<Customer>.
    This is a simple interface implemented by the list class. Since
    in this view we only want to iterate over this list, and we don't
    need any of the operations in the List class (eg Add, Remove, etc),
    it's better to use the IEnumerable interface, which allows use to
    iterate over the list. If in the future, we replace the List with a
    different data structure, as long as it is enumerable, our view code
    will remain unchanged.
*@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p>We don't have any customers yet.</p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var customer in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Details", "Customers", new { id = customer.id }, null)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: This should work. Try rebuild the solution

Comment: I tried already and still giving me the same error! @NithinChandran

Comment: `@System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(Html,customer.Name, "Details", "Customers", new { id = customer.id }, null)` try whether this works?

Comment: @NithinChandran it is showing this message after adding this line under (customer.name):**"argument 2 can't convert from method group to string"**

Comment: you must have missed some parentheses around that method

Comment: Also not working.. @NithinChandran

Answer (score 0):

You have property mismatch for `name`, Like in your model it is in small case `name`, but in view you are using `customer.Name` which should be `customer.name`

```
@Html.ActionLink(customer.name, "Details", ...
```

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get you-!! @Rajdeep Debnath